# Your vendor has not defined Win32::Process macro getExitCode

Tags: multithreading, perl, winapi

I'm trying to do the following:

```
my @procs;
// .. do some stuff
Win32::Process::Create($ProcessObj, "$COMSPEC", $cmd, 0, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, ".")
push ( @procs, $ProcessObj);

// .. do some stuff
my $exitcode = 0;
foreach my $proc (@procs)
{ 
  $proc->getExitCode($exitcode);
  if ($exitcode > 0 ) { 
    print "\t*** ERROR IN BUILD ***\n";
    exit ($exitcode);
  }
};
```

However, when this part of the script gets executed, I get the following message:

Your vendor has not defined Win32::Process macro getExitCode, used at C:..build.pl line 182. at C:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/RationalSDLC/common/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.6/MSWin32
-x86-multi-thread/Win32/Process.pm line 47,  line 1700.

I tried googling around, but couldn't find much. I'm pretty new to perl, so this has me stumped. Does `bless` come into play here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation [`Win32::Process Methods`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32%3a%3aProcess#METHODS) the correct name is `GetExitCode` (with a capital 'G').